# SQL Query to change Hibernate 5 CriteriaQuery

Tags: spring, hibernate

My SQL Query look like:

```
select rtnstatus_id,crs_filedt,(select rtnstatus_code from mst_rtnstatus where mst_rtnstatus.rtnstatus_id = txn_crs.rtnstatus_id )AS rtnstatus_code from txn_crs where mclient_id='44' and gstn_cid='10306' and rtnperiod_id=
(select rtnperiod_id from mst_rtnperiod where year_id=4 and month_id=10 and formtype_id=
(select formtype_id from mst_formtype where formtype_name='GSTR1')
and dlrtype_id=ifnull((select dlrtype_id from txn_clientdlr where mclient_id=44 and month_id=10 and year_id=4 order by clientdlr_id desc limit 1),(SELECT dlrtype_id FROM mst_dlrtype WHERE dlrtype_code='R')) order by rtnperiod_id desc limit 1 ) limit 1;
```

I Want to Change this query to CriteraQuery Hibernate 5, How i can do this,Plz  Help me..

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = _getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);
    Root<TxnCrs> root = criteriaQuery.from(TxnCrs.class);

    // For MstRtnstatus to get rtnstatusCode
    Subquery<Object> subQueryStatus = criteriaQuery.subquery(Object.class);   
    Root<MstRtnstatus> subRootStatus = subQueryStatus.from(MstRtnstatus.class);
    subQueryStatus.select(subRootStatus.get("rtnstatusCode")); 
    subQueryStatus.where(builder.equal(subRootStatus.get("rtnstatusId"),root.get("rtnstatusId")));

    // For MstFormtype to get formtypeId
    Subquery<Object> subQueryFormType = criteriaQuery.subquery(Object.class);   
    Root<MstFormtype> subRootFormType  = subQueryFormType.from(MstFormtype.class);
    subQueryFormType.select(subRootFormType.get("formtypeId")); 
    subQueryFormType.where(builder.equal(subRootFormType.get("formtypeName"),formType));

    //For TxnClientdlr to get dlrtypeId
    Subquery<Object> subQueryDlr = criteriaQuery.subquery(Object.class);   
    Root<TxnClientdlr> subRootDlr  = subQueryDlr.from(TxnClientdlr.class);
    subQueryDlr.select(subRootDlr.get("dlrtypeId"));
    subQueryDlr.where(builder.equal(subRootDlr.get("mclientId"),mclientId),builder.equal(subRootDlr.get("monthId"),monthId),
                                    builder.equal(subRootDlr.get("yearId"),yearId));

    // For MstDlrtype IF dlrtypeId get Null
     Subquery<Object> subQueryDlrType = criteriaQuery.subquery(Object.class);   
     Root<MstDlrtype> subRootDlrType  = subQueryDlrType.from(MstDlrtype.class);
     subQueryDlrType.select(subRootDlrType.get("dlrtypeId")); 
     subQueryDlrType.where(builder.equal(subRootDlrType.get("dlrtypeCode"),"R"));


    //For MstRtnperiod to get rtnperiodId
    Subquery<Object> subQueryPeriod = criteriaQuery.subquery(Object.class);   
    Root<MstRtnperiod> subRootPeriod = subQueryPeriod.from(MstRtnperiod.class);
    subQueryPeriod.select(subRootPeriod.get("rtnperiodId")); 
    subQueryPeriod.where(builder.equal(subRootPeriod.get("yearId"),yearId),builder.equal(subRootPeriod.get("monthId"),monthId),
                                 builder.equal(subRootPeriod.get("formtypeId"),subQueryFormType.getSelection()),
```

How i can write corect way ?

```
builder.equal(subRootPeriod.get("dlrtypeId"),subQueryDlr.getSelection()
                                    ,subRootPeriod.get("dlrtypeId"),subQueryDlrType.getSelection()));**


        criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get("rtnstatusId"),root.get("crsFiledt"),subQueryStatus.getSelection()).
        where(builder.equal(root.get("mclientId"),mclientId),builder.equal(root.get("gstnCid"),gstnCid),
                           builder.equal(root.get("rtnperiodId"),subQueryPeriod.getSelection())); 

        Query<Object[]> q=_getSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

Comment: Could you please simplify your code snippet. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: my sql query look like this formate